# Stack columns in numpy 2-dim array to get 1-dim array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to stack all columns in a 2-dimensional Numpy array into a 1-dimensional array.

I.e. I have:

```
x = np.array([[1, 3, 5],[2, 4, 6]])
```

And I want to get:

```
np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Is there a way to achieve this without a loop or list comprehension?

Comment: `y` before the loop is float dtype

Comment: A simpler way to do your concatenate: `np.concatenate([x[:,i] for i in range(3)])`

Comment: thanks - updated (both list comprehension and float dtype) - though obviously key element of the question is unchanged and the accepted answer is superior in my view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html):

```
x = np.array([[1, 3, 5],[2, 4, 6]])

res = x.ravel('F')  # or x.T.ravel()

# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `flatten` with `'F'`

```
x.flatten('F')
Out[114]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Nice! Never knew about `'F'`. Have stolen it, it works just as well with `ravel`.

Comment: @jpp yep :-) it is :-)